# evaluate Razor @Request.IsLocal in javascript script block

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the following Razor statement in javascript block but get "True is undefined" runtime error.  The @Request.IsLocal rendered as boolean value of True.  Thank you.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

 var test;
 if (@Request.IsLocal  || @Request.IsLocal == 'True')
 {
   test = 'local';
 }
 else
 {
   test = 'not loccal'
 }
 alert(test);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`True` is not javascript boolean. it is `true`

try following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var test;
 if ("@(Request.IsLocal)" == 'True')
 {
   test = 'local';
 }
 else
 {
   test = 'not loccal'
 }
 alert(test);
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var test;
 if (@Request.IsLocal.ToString().ToLowerInvarient())
 {
   test = 'local';
 }
 else
 {
   test = 'not loccal'
 }
 alert(test);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When razor executes your current code, it produces output like below

```
 var test;
 if (True  || True == 'True')
 {
   test = 'local';
 }
 else {
     test = 'not loccal';
 }
```

Assuming `Request.IsLocal` returns `true`.

And browser will try to execute this. Now the javascript framework thinks that `True` is a js variable, but it is not defined anywhere. Neither it is the boolean `true` (**javascript is case sensitive**). So the browser will complain that

> True is not defined

You can simplify your code by simply switching to the ternary operator expression which gets executed on server and return the value to your test variable.

This should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var test= '@(Request.IsLocal?Html.Raw("local"):Html.Raw("not local"))';
  alert(test);

</script>
```

If you check the view source of the page, you can see that there is no if conditions because those gets executed on the server.